# trying to get a cell value and its formating using custom function using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

here y is value and x is address of the y value, i want this custom formula to return the value and the font color but font color is not changing but value is returning , instead of cl if i put any value it is changing the color and i tried to print cl it is printing the value but activecell font is not changing

```
Function cellclr(y As Variant, x As Variant)
cl = Range(x).Font.ColorIndex
 
ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = cl 

Debug.Print cl

cellclr = y 

End Function
```

`

Comment: Looks like the final output of your function is whatever you entered as 'y'.  Also a UDF can only return the value to enter in the cell - `ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = cl` will not work as you're trying to change the colour of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do 2 things with 1 function is a bad design. A function should have a single task. E.g., get the color of the range:

```
Public Function GetColorOfText(myRange As Range) As Long
    GetColorOfText = myRange.Font.ColorIndex
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP is trying to get the cell to change colour using a UDF: _ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = cl_

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I am reading this and extrapolating from insufficient data - *i want this custom formula to return the value and the font color* only op knows what op wants...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am trying to lookup some values from an array table using index and match functions ,so while picking up those values i want the font color also to be copied as the original value, i got the value from the normal formula that i did without VBA but i want the color also in the same cell where i am getting the value so in place of "y" i put custom formula to get lookup value and address of the lookup value as "x" ,but i am not getting the desired output , thankyou

Comment: if the function can only do one operation then this code also shouldn't work but this is working fine,it is getting the color as well as returning the value                       Function cellclr(y As Variant
cl = Range(y.Address).Font.ColorIndex

ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = cl

cellclr = y

End Function